# Is it possible to use MapView by just adding maps.jar and not Google API?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to use MapView by just adding maps.jar and not compiling against Google API?
It's not working for me, but looking for a workaround so I don't have to update environments.

Comment: What's not working for you? The Google APIs?

Comment: I compile against the Android SDK and not the Google API SDK, that's not working.

I read on google api addon-on website that the Google API SDK includes: 
The Maps external library
The USB Open Accessory Library (only with API Levels 10 and 12+)
A fully-compliant Android system image (with the Maps library and other custom system components built in)
A sample Android application called MapsDemo
Full Maps library documentation (also available on this site)


I think I'm missing this: A fully-compliant Android system image (with the Maps library and other custom system components built in).

Comment: Right, the MapView, etc. aren't in the Android SDK, they are only in the Google API SDK, so you need to build against that.

Comment: Thanks Casey. From what I understand the Android SDK has android.jar and maps.jar, can I just include maps.jar and build against Android SDK and not Google API SDK? thanks.

Comment: I don't know.  I've never tried.

Comment: Have a look here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/